# Excel possible to fill two cells with one if-formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

I have searched on the internet to look if this is possible :

IF(logical test ; true value ; false value )

**This is what i try to make for example**

A2 `=IF( B2 = 20 ; "True"` & give C2 value "Closed" `; False )`

How can I do this?

Comment: It's not really clear what you're after. If that function was in C2, then =IF(B2 = 20,"True","False") then in C3 =IF(C2 = "True","Closed")  Would that not do what you wanted?  As far as I'm aware you cannot 'push' a value to another cell, only 'pull' one

Comment: Ooh if you can't Push a value to another cell then you already awnserd my question What i wanted to do is if i put this IF statement in say cell A2 and B2 had value 20 Then i want A2 get value True and C2 get value Closed.

Comment: Then it would need 2 IF calculations, one checking for B2=20 & the other either for the same thing, or for A2="True".

Comment: BTW, did you notice you don't need a 'false' value, only the 'true' is compulsory.

Comment: Thanks @Tetsujin for the awnser, but what i would like to try is to achieve a function in one column. I know your way works aswell! And yes i know i don't need a False aswell hehe

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't assign a value to another cell without VBA.

You could do two if formulas like:

```
A2=IF(B2=20,"True","False")
C2=IF(A2="True","Closed","")
```

For VBA you could do something like

```
sub test()
  For each c in range("B:B")
    If c = 20 then
      c.offset(-1,) = "True"
      c.offset(1,) = "Closed"
    End if
  Next c
end sub
```

Comment: Thanks i will try your VBA soon, i never used VBA before but have a programming background :)

Comment: @Beer something I didn't put in is, of course, you'll want to limit your for loop to probably a defined range or .usedrange

Comment: Well if you really want to help me then i need to give you a lot more information then this easy example, Like i work with 3 different sheets "Old" , "New" "Combine" What i try to do first is check Old and New ID's on duplicate and new/old entries for now i use this formule =IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(New!C9;Old!$B$3:$B$998;1;FALSE));IF(New!C9=0;"Empty";"NEW");"Duplicate") so i cant check for myself if it works, and for example if there is a New entrie get this row and paste it in the "Combine" Sheet

Comment: I can try to make a little dummy Excel example to show what i mean whit some values in it

Comment: If you want to use a macro, all of those things are relatively easy to implement. There are a lot of macro examples out there for checking duplicates and for combining rows/columns. If you are headed that way, give it a shot and then post another question showing your code and where you're getting stuck.

Comment: I will give it a Shot, The problem is that i try to make it easy for other people at my work to use it

Comment: For something simple like this, if you are trying to make it easy for your work colleagues, avoid VBA.

Comment: @Beer if you're worried coworkers won't know how to use it, just tie it to a button press for a button on the sheet.

Comment: @CallumDS33 Thats why i try to avoid VBA, but how can i achieve this using fomula's? And my question is asked here in a better way.  [link](http://superuser.com/questions/818237/how-to-combine-data-from-two-sheets-and-conditionally-format-rows-based-on-sheet/818288#818288)

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, and maybe for others searching for an answer in future, you can do it with a single formula if the cells are adjacent. E.g. if we were putting `TRUE`/`FALSE` in C2 and Closed in D2.
You do this with array formula...  To do this you need to:

1. Select BOTH cells C2 & D2
2. Enter the formula `=IF($B2=20,{TRUE,"Closed"},{FALSE,""})` and use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to set it

In this way, the IF is returning an array of values (either `TRUE,"Closed"` or `FALSE,""`) and, by entering this as an array formula with the two cells selected, Excel will populate both.

Unfortunately, you can't do this approach when the cells are split, like in A2/C2 as in your case :-(